# Python command exited with code 9009

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I am attempting to build a c++ solution in visual studio.

The error is as follows:

`error MSB3073: The command "python D:\...[file path]...\Source\VS2013\svnrev.py
:VCEnd" exited with code 9009.`

I have done some searching and the code 9009 apparently means a bad path. One possible reason for this is that the path contains spaces. On the visual studio error list there is a line break in between 'synrev.py' and ':VCEnd', so this may be the problem.

The error refers to a file called Microsoft.CppCommon.targets, the line supposedly being:

```
`<Exec Command="%(PreBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>`
```

According to previous questions on SO this problem can be fixed by adding quotation marks around the relevant spot but I'm not sure where this is (it seems like there are quotation marks around everything already!)

Another possible suggested cause is that there is no path linking to the necessary command. Checking the visual studio output gives:

`9>  'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
9>  operable program or batch file.`

The solution I am trying to build was obtained complete from the developers so it is possible that this is some sort of additional required file that they would just assume that I have installed. I have tried to search further but terms like 'Python command' are too generic and don't seem to be yielding helpful information.

I'm guessing this is some commonly used extension or add-on for running python in visual studio but I am not very experienced here - python is something I have never used and I haven't used visual studio before this project.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Go ahead and install python and make sure its on `PATH`

Comment: Any idea which python to install exactly for MSBuild to work? There are plenty of python dialects for .NET and Windows..

Comment: IronPython doesn't have python.exe so I believe I need another python dialect for MSBuild..

Comment: OK, it worked out with python from https://www.python.org

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to

- adjust properly **Python binary** call in **cdk.json**
- put binary on **PATH**

When running cdk deploy I also saw a 9009 error, in my case this was a format of python call in cdk.json.

**This statement gave 9009**

```
{
  "app": "python3 app.py"
}
```

**Works :**

```
{
  "app": "python app.py"
}
```

My use case, for reference :
Local python returns a version via :

```
C:\Users\XXX>python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

`python3 --version` returned **nothing**

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2657

In your case, it might be vice versa